# iterating over a dictionary while creating a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am learning python, and am trying to work on map and tuple. I have created a dictionary from a parsed file, and am parsing in another file. I want to iterate through the dictionary and replace the first element of each line of the parsed file with an ID obtained from the the dictionary

my dictionary:

```
for line in blast_lines:
    (transcript,swissProt,identity) = parse_blast(blast_line=line)
    transcript_to_protein[transcript] = swissProt
```

Parsing in the file, and creating a tuple that will have the value from the dictionary as the first element if the entry exists for that ID

```
def parse_matrix(matrix_line):
    matrixFields = matrix_line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
    protein = matrixFields[0] 
    if matrixFields[0] in transcript_to_protein:
            protein = transcript_to_protein.get(transcript)
            matrixFields[0] = protein
    return(tuple(matrixFields))
```

I'm not including all of my code here because I am sure my issue must be how I am iterating through the parse file and dictionary, but I'll include everything at the bottom.

Inputs:

blast (what is being stored in the dictionary)

```
c1000_g1_i1|m.799   gi|48474761|sp|O94288.1|NOC3_SCHPO  100.00  747 0   0   5   751 1   747 0.0  1506
```

for this line the transcript is c1000_g1_i1, the swiss prot is O94288.1

matrix (file being parsed)

```
c3833_g1_i2 4.00    0.07    16.84   26.37
```

I am trying to replace that first field (matrixFields[0]) with the swissProt from the dictionary if the value in the first field matches the key (transcript) from the dictionary.

I want an output that looks like this

```
Q09748.1    4.00    0.07    16.84   26.37
O60164.1    24.55   116.87  220.53  28.82
C5161_G1_I1 107.49  89.39   26.95   698.97
P36614.1    27.91   72.57   5.56    36.58
P37818.1    82.57   19.03   48.55   258.22
```

But am getting this:

```
O94423.1    4.00    0.07    16.84   26.37
O94423.1    24.55   116.87  220.53  28.82
C5161_G1_I1 107.49  89.39   26.95   698.97
O94423.1    27.91   72.57   5.56    36.58
O94423.1    82.57   19.03   48.55   258.22
```

Notice how 4 of them all have the same value instead of the individual transcripts from the dictionary

Full code:

```
transcript_to_protein = {};

def parse_blast(blast_line="NA"):
    fields = blast_line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
    queryIdString = fields[0]
    subjectIdString = fields[1]
    identity = fields[2]
    queryIds = queryIdString.split("|")
    subjectIds = subjectIdString.split("|")
    transcript = queryIds[0].upper()
    swissProt = subjectIds[3]
    base = swissProt.split(".")[0]
    return(transcript, swissProt, identity)

blast_output = open("/scratch/RNASeq/blastp.outfmt6")
blast_lines = blast_output.readlines()

for line in blast_lines:
    (transcript,swissProt,identity) = parse_blast(blast_line=line)
    transcript_to_protein[transcript] = swissProt

def parse_matrix(matrix_line):
    matrixFields = matrix_line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
    matrixFields[0] = matrixFields[0].upper()
    protein = matrixFields[0]
    if matrixFields[0] in transcript_to_protein:
            protein = transcript_to_protein.get(transcript)
            matrixFields[0] = protein
    return(tuple(matrixFields))

def tuple_to_tab_sep(one_tuple):
    tab = "\t"
    return tab.join(one_tuple)

matrix = open("/scratch/RNASeq/diffExpr.P1e-3_C2.matrix")

newline = "\n"

list_of_de_tuples = map(parse_matrix,matrix.readlines())

list_of_tab_sep_lines = map(tuple_to_tab_sep, list_of_de_tuples)
print(newline.join(list_of_tab_sep_lines))
```

Answer (score 2):

First there's a bug in `parse_blast()`—it's not returning the tuple `(transcript,swissProt,identity)`, instead it's returning `(transcript,base,identity)` and `base` doesn't include the missing information.

**Update**

Secondly, there's also a bug in `parse_matrix()`. The first field read from the file does not have the missing information, however, that's what it puts in the tuple it returns when `matrixFields[0]` is in the `transcript_to_protein` dictionary.

Just fixing one won't solve the problem by itself.

Comment: With that corrected it is still printing the same value for all the replaced fields instead of iterating through the dictionary, instead printing off the last value for all of them

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem might be in the parseblast function.
For line

```
c1000_g1_i1|m.799   gi|48474761|sp|O94288.1|NOC3_SCHPO  100.00  747 0   0   5   751 1   747 0.0  1506

subjectIdString = fields[1]
```

So subjectIdString would be  gi|48474761|sp|O94288.1|NOC3_SCHPO

And then

```
swissProt = subjectIds[3]
```

swissProt would be O94288.1, which the function further splits, using . on line

```
base = swissProt.split(".")[0]
```

The end result would be that swissprot would be 094288 and not |O94288.1, which it seems you are expecting. I would recommend testing that function on single line input till you get the desired output

Comment: It is working fine for single line, the issue is that it just keeps printing the same swissprot id for all lines instead of the ones that match the key in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The error was in my dictionary call, because I wanted to match matrixFields[0] with the transcript from the dictionary, I was trying to search the dictionary using `if matrixFields[0] in transcript_to_protein:` but instead needed to assign the field

```
trasncript = matrixfields[0]
if transcript in transcript_to_protein:
        protein = transcript_to_protein.get(transcript)
```